# Change bitbucket url repository in android studio

Tags: android-studio, version-control, bitbucket

Fellows,

Despite I have many years of development I am newbie in version control source. So I need your help to change an url repository of Bitbucket in Android Studio to another one in Bitbucket as well. I have tried to find out a solution but I didn't have successful.

Comment: From command line you just need to do `git remote set-url origin git://new.url`

Answer (score 3):

cd "repo path on your device"

git remote -v (to get your current URL)

git remote set-url origin "new Url"

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your repo path on your device
open **.get** folder (hidden folder)
open **config** file for edit
you will find the old repo link, change it by the new one

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://old_url_here.git
```

Change it by

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://new_url_here.git
```